# I want to get paypal subscription details

Tags: python, python-3.x, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have many subscription created manually with paypal button.
Now I want to get details of subscriptions. (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_merchant-hub)
How can I do it?

I just tried to use rest API:

```
import paypalrestsdk
import logging

paypal_api = paypalrestsdk.configure({
  "mode": "sandbox", # sandbox or live
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXX",
  "client_secret": "XXXXXXXX" })


# Fetch Payment
payment_history = paypalrestsdk.Payment.all({"count": 10})
print("List Payment:")
for payment in payment_history.payments:
    print("  -> Payment[%s]" % (payment.id))
```

The response is a empty list. I read that this code only works with subscription made with SDK.
So I tried with this one:

```
from paypal import PayPalInterface
paypal_api = PayPalInterface(API_USERNAME="xxxxxxxxxxxxapi1.gmail.com",
                             API_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                             API_SIGNATURE="xxxxxxxxxxx",
                             DEBUG_LEVEL=0,
                             HTTP_TIMEOUT=30)

transactions = paypal_api.transaction_search(STARTDATE='2019-01-01T00:00:00Z',STATUS="Success")
print(transactions)
```

but response is this:

> {'ACK': ['Success'],  'BUILD': [some_numbers],  'CORRELATIONID':
>   [id],  'TIMESTAMP': ['2019-02-24T21:49:47Z'],  'VERSION':
>   ['98.0']}

How can I get infos like, costumer email, address, profile info etc?